# Can I store methods in an array?

Tags: methods, swift

Consider the following code:

```
class Test {

    func func1(arg1: Int) -> Void {
        println(arg1)
    }

    var funcArr: Array< (Int) -> Void > = [func1] // (!) 'Int' is not a subtype of 'Test'
}
```

I'm trying to store the method `func1`in an array, but as you can see, this doesn't seem to work because `func1`supposedly only takes an argument of type `Test`. I assume this has something to do with methods needing to be associated with an object.

For some more clarification, have a look at the following code where I let swift infer the type of the array:

```
class Test {

    func func1(arg1: Int) -> Void {
        println(arg1)
    }

    var funcArr = [func1]
}

Test().funcArr[0](Test()) // Compiles, but nothing gets printed.
Test().funcArr[0](1) // (!) Type 'Test' does not conform to protocol 'IntegerLiteralConvertible'
Test().func1(1) // Prints '1'
```

A possible workaround for this problem is moving `func1`outside of the class like so:

```
func func1(arg1: Int) -> Void {
    println(arg1)
}

class Test {
    var funcArr = [func1]
}

Test().funcArr[0](1) // Prints '1'
```

This works fine for this simple example, but is less than ideal when I actually need to operate on an Object of type `Test` in the function. I can of course add another parameter to the function to pass an instance of `Test`to the function, but this seems clunky.

**Is there any way I can store methods in an array?**

Ultimately, what I want to be able to do is `testObject.funcArr[someInt](someParam)` and have that function work as a method belonging to `testObject`. Any clever workarounds are of course also welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Instance methods in swift are just curried functions](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/), and the first argument is implicitly an instance of the class (i.e. `self`). And that's why these two are equivalent:

```
Test().func1(0)
Test.func1(Test())(0)
```

So when you try to put that function in the array, you're reveling its real nature: the method `func1` on `Test` is actually this class method:

```
class func1(self_: Test)(arg1: Int)
```

So when you refer to simply `func1` (without an "instance context") it has type `Test -> Int -> Void`, instead of the expected `Int -> Void`, and that's why you get the error

> `Int` is not a subtype of `Test`

So the real issue is that when you store the methods in `funcArr` the instance is not known yet (or if you will, you're referring the function at a class level). You can work around this using a computed property:

```
var funcArr: [Int -> Void] { return [func1] } // use a computed property
```

Or another valuable option could be simply to acknowledge the real type of `func1` and explicitly passing the instance. E.g.

```
...
var funcArr = [func1]
...

let test = Test()
let func1 = test.funcArr[0]
func1(test)(0) // prints 0
```

---

### update

Freely inspired by this other Q/A ([Make self weak in methods in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613783/make-self-weak-in-methods-in-swift)) I came up with a similar solution that stores the method references.

```
func weakRef<T: AnyObject, A, B>(weakSelf: T, method: T -> A -> B) -> A -> B {
    return { [unowned weakSelf] in { a in method(weakSelf)(a) } }()
}

class Test {
    var methodRefs: [Int -> Void] = []

    init() {
        methodRefs.append(weakRef(self, Test.func1))
    }

    func func1(arg1: Int) {
        println(arg1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I went for using your second option but I'm hesitant to accept this answer. Especially since something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25613783/3684713) seems to work, but I can't seem to make the reference to self weak like is done there. I also wonder if your first solution doesn't introduce a memory leak.

Comment: @overactor The first solution should not introduce a memory leak, since the array containing the references to the instance methods is not held by the instance itself, but just returned to the caller. I'll update my answer with a few more considerations

Comment: @overactor check it out.

Answer (score 2):

In order to store a method, you should remember that the method is invoked on a class instance. What's actually stored in the array is a curried function:

```
(Test) -> (Int) -> Void
```

The first function takes a class instance and returns another function, the actual `(Int) -> Void` method, which is then invoked on that instance.

To make it more explicit, the array type is:

```
var funcArr: [(Test) -> (Int) -> Void] = [Test.func1]
```

Then you can invoke the method with code like this:

```
var test = Test()
var method = test.funcArr[0]
method(test)(1)
```

Suggested reading: [Curried Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-XID_615)