# How to set a weak reference to a closure/function in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

In `HMSegmentedControl`, I'd like to set the `segmentedControl.indexChangeBlock` to an instance method to handle the action.
The official example is: https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl/blob/master/HMSegmentedControlExample/HMSegmentedControlExample/ViewController.m (Line 63 ~ 68), but that's Objective-C.

In Swift, functions are first class citizens. So I wanna set an instance method to this block property.
But my code would lead to a circular reference, it seems that I should define a weak reference:

```
class ExampleVC: UIViewController {
    var segmentedControlIndex: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      let segmentedControl3 = HMSegmentedControl(sectionImages: ... , sectionSelectedImages: ... )
      segmentedControl3.frame = ...
      segmentedControl3.indexChangeBlock = someInstanceMethod
    }

    func someInstanceMethod(index: Int) {
      segmentedControlIndex = index
    }
}
```

However, I cannot define a weak reference to a non-class type. What can I do? Is it legal to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make self weak in methods in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613783/make-self-weak-in-methods-in-swift)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of defining weak reference to the closure, you should use ["Capture List"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-XID_105) in the closure.

```
segmentedControl3.indexChangeBlock = { [unowned self] in self.someInstanceMethod($0) }
```

As far as I know, this is the only way to avoid strong reference cycles.

Comment: `[weak self]` will break the reference cycle and is generally less prone to breakage when code gets refactored or view hierarchies are reorganized.

Answer (score 21):

`[unowned self]` is dangerous. What this does is to tell the runtime 'Assume self has not been released, don't worry about checking.' If `self` does get released in the meantime, your application will SEGFAULT.

In this case, `{ [weak self] in self?.someInstanceMethod($0) }` will break the reference cycle, and turns into a `no-op` if `self` is released.

`[weak self]` is always safe, while `[unowned self]` can introduce app crashes if you modify **other** areas of your code (like view hierarchy, for example)...

Comment: The HMSegmentedControl is owned by the ExampleVC, so you will never have self to be nil. And as Apple say: use unowned whenever it is possible.

Comment: Unowned is still fundamentally unsafe. I know it's good to follow what Apple recommends, and this is probably for performance reasons, but I stand by my recommendation, for the reasons I outlined.

Comment: I agree with you, weak will always be safe. The point was just unowned is not just assume it is not release, it is more, as the developer, I say it will never be nil. But I also agree with you I prefer to be 100% sure than let someone say it is safe, jump.