# weak to non class types to avoid memory leak

Tags: swift

I've got a memory leak in this case, if I pass a reference to any method, the self comes with it which increases it's reference count I guess, how can I make non class types to be weak

```
public class Observer {

    weak private var method: ((message: AnyObject) -> ())! //error here

    weak private var context: AnyObject!

}

public init(method: (AnyObject -> ())?, context: AnyObject?) {
    self.method = method
    self.context = context
}
```

in another class I guess `self.callback` creates a strong reference to the caller object and passes on.

```
var observer = Observer(method: self.callback, context: self) //pass of self.callback is a strong reference
```

***Edit:***

Working on the above, my attempt using an example that further clarifies the situation using two classes. `deinit` never gets called.

```
class Test {

    private var ref: Observer?

    init() {
        ref = Observer(method: self.callback, context: self)
    }

    func callback(message: AnyObject) {

    }

    deinit {
        println("deinit test")
    }

}

public class Observer {

private var method: ((message: AnyObject) -> ())?
weak private var context: AnyObject!

public init(method: (AnyObject -> ())?, context: AnyObject?) {
    self.method = method
    self.context = context
}

deinit {
    println("deinit observer")
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your code, it seems like you are talking about a retain cycle where the `Test` object holds onto the `Observer` object through the variable `ref`, the `Observer` object holds onto the closure formed by doing `self.callback`, which holds onto `self`.

Generally in such cases, you don't want the closure property itself to be weak. Rather, you want the closure to capture a weak reference to `self` (the `Test` object is passing a "callback" to itself to another object). However, that is somewhat confusing here as we are not explicitly using closure syntax (rather, you are getting a closure by accessing a method on an instance and not calling it). The problem of capturing a weak reference to `self` in this case was covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613783/make-self-weak-in-methods-in-swift).

The best solution is:

```
ref = Observer(method: {[unowned self] in self.callback($0)}, context: self)
```

Comment: possible to have a named parameter in this example instead of $0, I'd like to use `[weak self]` so in case if the object `Test` gets deallocated, there won't be runtime error, do you approve this?

Comment: @user2727195: sure, you can do that if your situation requires it

Comment: I never saw in any example to define parameter names next to `[unowned self]` so i could use a name instead of $0, any idea on how the syntax would be

Comment: @user2727195: something like `{[unowned self] x in self.callback(x)}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Observer {

    private var method: ((message: AnyObject) -> ())?
    weak private var context: AnyObject!

    public init(method: (AnyObject -> ())?, context: AnyObject?) {
        self.method = method
        self.context = context
    }
}
```

I tried it and it doesn't create a strong reference cycle. But I also tried with ! instead of ?, and that didn't caused as well, and I hope somebody is out there to explain that.

Comment: thanks for the attempt, can you please try using two classes above

Comment: how do you force the object to be deinited?

Comment: I mean i tried that implementing in a navigation controller and it was deallocated.