# Capture a method weakly

Tags: swift, swift4, swift5

Note: This question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818276/weak-to-non-class-types-to-avoid-memory-leak/27853497#27853497), but for Swift 4 or 5.

Say I have a class that captures a closure:

```
class CallbackHolder {
  typealias Callback = (String) -> Void

  var callback: Callback

  init(_ callback: @escaping Callback) {
    self.callback = callback
  }

  func useCallback() {
    self.callback("Hi!")
  }
}
```

This class simply holds a callback in a variable, and has a function that uses that callback.

Now, say I have a client class that owns such a callback holder. This class wants the callback holder to call one of its methods as the callback:

```
class Client {
  func callback(string: String) {
    print(string)
  }

  lazy var callbackOwner = CallbackOwner(callback: callback)

  deinit {
    print("deinit")
  }
}
```

This class has a callback, a callback owner that calls that callback, and a deinit that prints something so that we know whether we have a retain cycle (no deinit = retain cycle).

We can test our setup with the following test function:

```
func test() {
   Client().callbackOwner.useCallback()
}
```

We want the test function to print both `Hi!` and `deinit`, so that we know that the callback works, and that the client does not suffer from a retain cycle.

The above Client implementation does in fact have a retain cycle -- passing the `callback` method to the callback owner causes the owner to retain the client strongly, causing a cycle.

Of course, we can fix the cycle by replacing

```
  lazy var callbackOwner = CallbackOwner(callback: callback)
```

with

```
  lazy var callbackOwner = CallbackOwner(callback: { [weak self] in 
    self?.callback($0) 
  })
```

This works, but:

- it is tedious (compare the amount of code we now need)
- it is dangerous (every new client of my CallbackOwner class must remember to do it this way, even though the original way is completely valid syntax, otherwise they will get a retain cycle)

So I am looking for a better way. I would like to capture the callback weakly *at the CallbackOwner*, not at the client. That way, new clients don't have to be aware of the danger of the retain cycle, and they can use my CallbackOwner in the most intuitive way possible.

So I tried to change CallbackOwner's callback property to

```
  weak var callback: Callback?
```

but of course, Swift only allows us to capture class types weakly, not closures or methods.

At the time when [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27853497/1469018) answer was written, there did not seem to be a way to do achieve what I'm looking for, but that was over 4 years ago. Has there been any developments in recent Swift versions that would allow me to pass a method to a closure-capturing object without causing a retain cycle?

Comment: The previous answer is still correct. Nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Well one obvious way to do this would be to not hold a reference to `CallbackHolder` in `Client` i.e.

```
class Client {
    func callback(string: String) {
        print(string)
    }

    var callbackOwner: CallbackHolder { return CallbackHolder(callback) }

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```

In the above case, I'd probably make `CallbackHolder` a `struct` rather than a class.

Personally, I don't see any value in wrapping the callback in a class at all. Just pass the callback around, or even `Client`. Maybe make a protocol for it to adhere to

```
protocol Callbackable
{
    func callback(string: String)
}

extension Callbackable
{
    func useCallback() {
        self.callback(string: "Hi!")
    }
}


class Client: Callbackable {
    func callback(string: String) {
        print(string)
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

func test(thing: Callbackable) {
    thing.useCallback()
}

test(thing: Client())
```

Comment: In my simple example, yes, it would probably be better to eliminate the callback holder. My real-world scenario though is a debouncer class. A single client class may have multiple debouncers for debouncing various actions, and each debouncer should run a different callback. So then it is important that the client actually inits and references those debouncer objects (otherwise they wouldn't work as debouncers), and that the debouncers can use any methods or closures as callbacks, and not a single, fixed-named function.