# Holding and releasing Closures in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, closures

I'm looking to make an observable property without relying on a reactive 3rd party lib / framework.

I read this and came up with a similar solution to their Observable Properties answer...

https://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/11/swift-kvo-alternatives.html

Theirs

```
class Observable<T> {

  let didChange = Event<(T, T)>()
  private var value: T

  init(_ initialValue: T) {
    value = initialValue
  }

  func set(newValue: T) {
    let oldValue = value
    value = newValue
    didChange.raise(oldValue, newValue)
  }

  func get() -> T {
    return value
  }
}
```

Mine

```
public class Observable<V> {

    public var value: V { didSet { for observer in observers { observer(value) } }}
    private var observers = [(V) -> Void]()

    public init(_ initital: V) {
        value = initital
    }

    public func observe(with closure: @escaping (V) -> Void) {
        observers.append(closure)
    }
}
```

the only difference is I want to capture an array of closures instead of using `Event` and `addHander`... the reason being I want to provide the syntax of passing the value through rather than have the consumers of my code make a function every time and again to not rely on any 3rd party code.

I'm not sure how these closures could automatically be removed from the array once their owners are deallocated. I'm guessing they can't which is why `addHandler` is used, I'm just hoping someone out there more knowledgable than me can shed some light on the issue.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: FYI https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633855/weak-reference-to-closure-in-swift

Comment: So the key difference is your impl accepts a closure, while the event version takes a function?

Comment: Why don't you use notification center which does the exact same thing? By the way, the trick used by notification center is to return an object which will remove the observer when deallocated. That means that the observer will exist while you hold that object strongly.

Comment: @hackape they also use some 3rd party framework `Event` for the KVO

Comment: @Sulthan it's a good idea... let me update

Comment: @hackape re: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633855/weak-reference-to-closure-in-swift the short answer is no for sure, but i'm wondering how the same effect could be made.. I think the notification way is the answer

Comment: @Sulthan can you explain a little more? not sure how to do the thing you are suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I come up with this solution:

```swift
class Wrapper<V> {
    var observer: (V) -> Void
    public init(_ b: @escaping (V) -> Void) {
        observer = b
    }
}

class Observable<V> {
    public var value: V { didSet {
        let enumerator = observers.objectEnumerator()
        while let wrapper = enumerator?.nextObject() {
            (wrapper as! Wrapper<V>).observer(value)
        }
    }}
    private var observers = NSMapTable<AnyObject, Wrapper<V>>(keyOptions: [.weakMemory], valueOptions: [.strongMemory])

    public init(_ initital: V) {
        value = initital
    }

    public func observe(_ subscriber: AnyObject, with closure: @escaping (V) -> Void) {
        let wrapper = Wrapper(closure)
        observers.setObject(wrapper, forKey: subscriber)
    }
}
```

The final API require subscriber to identify themselves at calling:

```
Observable.observe(self /* <-- extra param */) { /* closure */ }
```

Although we cannot weak ref a closure, but with `NSMapTable`, we can weak ref the `subscriber` object, then use it as a weak key to track observer closure. This allow deallocation of `subscriber` thus automatically cleanup outdated observers.

Finally, here's the code for a demo. Expand the snippet and copy-paste to swift playground and see it live.

```js
import Foundation

func setTimeout(_ delay: TimeInterval, block:@escaping ()->Void) -> Timer {
    return Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: delay, target: BlockOperation(block: block), selector: #selector(Operation.main), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

class Wrapper<V> {
    var observer: (V) -> Void
    public init(_ b: @escaping (V) -> Void) {
        observer = b
    }
}

class Observable<V> {
    public var value: V { didSet {
        let enumerator = observers.objectEnumerator()
        while let wrapper = enumerator?.nextObject() {
            (wrapper as! Wrapper<V>).observer(value)
        }
    }}
    private var observers = NSMapTable<AnyObject, Wrapper<V>>(keyOptions: [.weakMemory], valueOptions: [.strongMemory])

    public init(_ initital: V) {
        value = initital
    }
    
    public func observe(_ subscriber: AnyObject, with closure: @escaping (V) -> Void) {
        let wrapper = Wrapper(closure)
        observers.setObject(wrapper, forKey: subscriber)
    }
}

class Consumer {
    private var id: String

    public init(_ id: String, _ observable: Observable<Int>) {
        self.id = id
        observable.observe(self) { val in
            print("[\(id)]", "ok, i see value changed to", val)
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("[\(id)]", "I'm out")
    }
}

func demo() -> Any {
    let observable = Observable(1)
    var list = [AnyObject]()

    list.append(Consumer("Alice", observable))
    list.append(Consumer("Bob", observable))
    
    observable.value += 1

    // pop Bob, so he goes deinit
    list.popLast()
    
    // deferred
    setTimeout(1.0) {
        observable.value += 1
        observable.value += 1
    }

    return [observable, list]
}

// need to hold ref to see the effect
let refHolder = demo()
```

---

**Edit:**

As OP @Magoo commented below, the `Wrapper` object is not properly deallocated. Even though the `subscriber` object is successfully deallocated, and corresponding key is removed from `NSMapTable`, the `Wrapper` remain active as an entry held in `NSMapTable`.

Did a bit of test and found this is indeed the case, unexpectedly. Some further research reveal an unfortunate fact: it's a caveat in `NSMapTable`'s implementation.

[This post](http://cocoamine.net/blog/2013/12/13/nsmaptable-and-zeroing-weak-references/) explain the reason behind thoroughly. Quote directly from [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/#X10_8Notes):

> However, weak-to-strong NSMapTables are not currently recommended, as the strong values for weak keys which get zero’d out do not get cleared away (and released) until/unless the map table resizes itself.

Hmm, so basically Apple just think it's ok to keep them alive in memory until a resize takes place. Reasonable from GC strategy POV.

Conclusion: no chance it'd be handled if `NSMapTables` implementation remains the same.

However it shouldn't be a problem for most case. This `Observer` impl works as intended. And as long as the `Wrapper` don't do anything fishy and closure don't hold strong ref, only negative impact is just some extra memory footprint.

I do have a fix though, you can use `weak -> weak` map, so `Wrapper` as a weak value get dealloc too. But that'll require `.observe()` returns the `Wrapper` then `Consumer` get hold to a ref to it. I'm not keen on this idea, API not ergonomic to end user. I'd rather live with some memory overhead in favor of better API.

**Edit 2:**

I don't like the aforementioned fix cus the resulting API is not friendly. I saw no way around but @Magoo managed to NAIL IT! Using `objc_setAssociatedObject` API, which I never heard about before. Make sure to checkout [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55788944/3617380) for detail, it's awesome.

Comment: For the record I don't think that API is bad at all, but in my implementation I changed the wording to `public func addObserver(_ object: AnyObject, closure: @escaping (V) -> Void) {`

Comment: So, doing some tests reveals the `Wrapper` object is still hanging around... :( you can hold a weak ref to one and fire it's closure

Comment: Edited your code snippet to my example, should be easy to remake in a viewController project

Comment: @Magoo I'll look into it later

Comment: @Magoo see my update. I do have a fix though, you can use `weak -> weak` map, so `Wrapper` as a weak value get dealloc too. But that'll require `Consumer` to get hold to a ref to the `Wrapper` object. I'm not keen on this idea, not ergonomic to end user.

Comment: I agree with your assessment too... and I still like this implementation... I have an idea about tidying up inside... I'll share with you soon

Comment: `setAssociatedObject` :)

Comment: @Magoo Wow, I don't even know there exists such method. Good to know! Why don't they port it to swift, very useful tool.

Comment: @Magoo however I don't think it's good idea to append this information to my answer. It's already long enough, plus your finding is actually new, making it more than an "edit". Why don't you write a separate answer then I link to it?

Comment: Yeah me either until today! Super useful.
Absolutely I will re-edit and add another answer... I just wanted to show you first. Thanks for all your effort with this question.

Comment: @Magoo no pb man. I also learn new stuff, really worth it. Thank you for the good question

Comment: added my answer if you'd like to link to it

Comment: @Magoo linked, awesome solution!

Comment: Cheers mate, really happy with how it turned out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

OK so @hackape answer with `objc_setAssociatedObject`

```
public class Observable<V> {

    private class ClosureWrapper<V> {
        var closure: (V) -> Void
        public init(_ closure: @escaping (V) -> Void) {
            self.closure = closure
        }
    }

    private var observers = NSMapTable<AnyObject, ClosureWrapper<V>>(keyOptions: [.weakMemory], valueOptions: [.weakMemory])
    public var value: V { didSet { notify() } }

    public init(_ initital: V) {
        value = initital
    }

    public func addObserver(_ object: AnyObject, skipFirst: Bool = true, closure: @escaping (V) -> Void) {
        let wrapper = ClosureWrapper(closure)
        let reference = "observer\(UUID().uuidString)".replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
        observers.setObject(wrapper, forKey: object)

        // Giving the closure back to the object that is observing
        // allows ClosureWrapper to die at the same time as observing object
        objc_setAssociatedObject(object, reference, wrapper, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        if !skipFirst { closure(value) }
    }

    private func notify() {
        let enumerator = observers.objectEnumerator()
        while let wrapper = enumerator?.nextObject() { (wrapper as? ClosureWrapper<V>)?.closure(value) }
    }
}
```

This guy also remade the `NSMapTable` in Swift using a really similar method https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85709/generic-nsmaptable-replacement-written-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, and likely safest, solution would be use the exact implementation you have, but make sure all callers use `[weak self]` and guard that `self` still exists before performing any actions/side effects.

This way when the array of closures is executed, any that had their creator already dealloc will simply immediately return when called.

```
// called from outside class
observer.observe { [weak self] in 
    guard strongSelf = self else { return }

    // do work using `strongSelf`
}
```

If the observer is going to be used by a lot of instances that are constantly deallocating, I'd recommend adding a remove observer function. To do this you'd probably want to return a string on the `observe` call and then use it for removing the closure. Something along the lines of this:

```
public typealias ObserverIdentifier = String
public class Observable<V> {
    public var value: V { didSet { for observer in observers.values { observer(value) } }}
    private var observers = [ObserverIdentifier  : (V) -> Void]()

    public init(_ initital: V) {
        value = initital
    }

    @discardableResult public func observe(with closure: @escaping (V) -> Void) -> ObserverIdentifier {
        let identifier = UUID().uuidString
        observers[identifier] = closure
        return identifier
    }

    public func remove(identifier: ObserverIdentifier) {
        observers.removeValue(forKey: identifier)
    }
}
```

Because you are using `[weak self]`, removing the observer on deallocation is simply a nice thing to do to avoid some additional no-ops, but still completely safe if not removed.

Comment: Using a dictionary instead of an array is the first step. I am not sure you should use `discardableResult` because that means the observer cannot be ever removed. I would prefer the solution used by `NotificationCenter` which would remove the observer automatically unless you hold to the return value.

Comment: Casey I'm worried about the consumers of my API... yeah they should be using weak self but I want to throw the closure away when the owner dies... I want the burden to be with me not my consumers.
@Sulthan I was thinking that too... I'm going to update my question with a notification example

Comment: If the code is for consumers, then definitely don't have the `@discardableResult`! Internally I find it very useful and perfectly safe to use.