# ReactiveCocoa retain cycle when passing closure as parameter

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

I'm using ReactiveCocoa in Swift as followed:

```
registerButton?.rac_signalForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside).subscribeNextAs(registerButtonTapped)

private func registerButtonTapped(button: UIButton){
    // Method here
}
```

Which creates a retain cycle.

I know the solution is as followed:

```
registerButton?.rac_signalForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside).subscribeNextAs({ [weak self] (button:UIButton) in
    self?.registerButtonTapped(button)
})
```

But this enforces me to use the `subscribeNextAs` block and not the nicer oneliner passing the method.

Any idea how to use the oneliner without a retain cycle?

Comment: I would argue that this is bit of an anti pattern: One of the advantages of RAC is to move from callbacks to more concise code, and here you are doing the exact opposite.

Comment: Totally agree, however, I find myself using callbacks at multiple locations. Passing a method sometimes makes sense, although the example I'm giving here is quite bad. For instance, a mapping method is something I share across signals.

Comment: Okay, reuse of this kind makes sense to me as well. Have you seen solutions proposed here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613783/make-self-weak-in-methods-in-swift

Comment: The answer linked to by @JakubVano looks  Probably how I would approach this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, so [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613783/make-self-weak-in-methods-in-swift) linked to by Jakub Vano is great, but it's not *quite* general-purpose. It constrains you to use a function that has no parameters and returns `Void`. Using Swift generics, we can be a little smarter about this to use functions that accept *any* parameters and use *any* return type.

So the first thing is that, for `weak` relationships, you *must* use an object. Structs can't be referred to weakly. So we'll constrain the instance type to be `AnyObject`, a protocol that all classes conform to. Our function declaration looks like the following:

```
func applyWeakly<Type: AnyObject, Parameters, ReturnValue>(instance: Type, function: (Type -> Parameters -> ReturnValue)) -> (Parameters -> ReturnValue?)
```

So the function takes an instance, and a function that takes an instance and returns a `Parameters -> ReturnValue` function. Remember, closures and functions in Swift are interchangeable. Neat!

Note that we're having to return an *optional* `ReturnValue` because the instance might become `nil`. I'll address later how to get around this.

OK so now you need to know a really neat trick: [Swift instance methods are actually just curried class methods](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/), which is perfect for our needs

So now we can call `applyWeakly` with the *class* function that returns an instance function when you call it with an instance. The `applyWeakly` implementation is fairly straightforward.

```
func applyWeakly<Type: AnyObject, Parameters, ReturnValue>(instance: Type, function: (Type -> Parameters -> ReturnValue)) -> (Parameters -> ReturnValue?) {
    return { [weak instance] parameters -> ReturnValue? in
        guard let instance = instance else { return nil }
        return function(instance)(parameters)
    }
}
```

Super. So how would you use this? Let's take a very simple example. We have  a class with a parameter that holds a closure, and that closure will refer to its own instance method (this is just demonstrating the reference cycle problem – your question involves two objects but I'm simplifying down to one).

```
class MyClass {
    var closure: (String -> String?)!

    func doThing(string: String) -> String {
        return "hi, \(string)"
    }

    init() {
        closure = doThing // WARNING! This will cause a reference cycle
        closure = applyWeakly(self, function: MyClass.doThing)
    }
}
```

We have to use an implicitly-unwrapped optional for the `closure` type so we can refer to an instance method in our `init` function. That's ok, just a limitation of this example.

So this is great, and will work, but it's kind of icky that our `closure` type is `String -> String?` but our `doThing` type is `String -> String`. In order to return a non-optional string, we need to either force-unwrap an optional () or use `unowned`.

Unowned references are like weak ones, except they're non-zeroing. That means if the objects is deallocated and you use a reference to it, your app will explode. In your case, though, it's applicable. [Here's more info](http://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift) on unowned vs weak.

The `applyUnowned` function would look like this:

```
func applyUnowned<Type: AnyObject, Parameters, ReturnValue>(instance: Type, function: (Type -> Parameters -> ReturnValue)) -> (Parameters -> ReturnValue) {
    return { [unowned instance] parameters -> ReturnValue in
        return function(instance)(parameters)
    }
}
```

I hope that clarifies things – happy to answer any follow-up questions. This problem has been in the back of my mind for a while, and I'm glad to have finally recorded my thoughts down.

Comment: Thanks Ash, I couldn't wish a better clarified answer! Seems to be the best solution to what I want to achieve, although I'm not sure if this will make things more readable and better then just writing down the closure (taking my example).

I'll use your example in future implementations and will check out what suits the best. Thanks!